# Library edit form is empty

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I'm trying to customize the edit form for a library (site pages library, to be specific) but the edit form is blank. Other libraries on the site (document library, custom lists, etc.) work fine but when I create a new edit form for the site pages library it is blank. I look at the .aspx file in sharepoint designer and I see the columns in the code but nothing is displayed.

It is worth mentioning this is for a custom content type that inherits the "web part page" type.

This is the table element for the 'Title' column

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Title</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="Edit"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Which is a child of this element:

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowedit">
```

How can I make these columns visible?